# How check the user is valid or not in Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I try laravel passport.But i can't understand anything.
**How check the user is valid or not in Laravel Passport**

Comment: Have you gone through [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport) and reproduce examples from there on clean Laravel installation first?

Answer (score 4):

You can check this.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport

I will briefly explain.
After you setup Laravel-Passport to your project you should edit driver key in config/auth.php file.

```
'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
```

And then make migration. Check your database. There must be tables about laravel passport.

You should post the datas below to '/user' url.

```
'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
'client_id' => 'client-id',
'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
'username'=>'username',
'password'=>'password',
'scope'=>''
```

You must edit grant_type, client_id and client_secret keys according to values in the oauth_clients table in your database.

If you get Access-Control-Allow-Origin error you must create a middleware to allow all requests.

```
if (isset($request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
            $origin = $request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization');
        }
        return $next($request);
```